# Iterate through PHP object with foreach (Stripe Customer)

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to iterate over the metadata stored in a Stripe customer object.

I can count the number of items:

```
echo count($matchUser->data[0]->metadata);
```

Which gives me '2' as expected.  But:

```
foreach($matchUser->data[0]->metadata as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
    echo $value;
    echo "hello";
}
```

returns nothing.

Var dump of the metadata is as follows:

```
object(Stripe\StripeObject)#67 (2) { ["testitem"]=> string(5) "hello" ["password_hash"]=> string(6) "myhash" }
```

Comment: and what does `var_dump($matchUser->data[0]->metadata)` and `echo gettype($matchUser->data[0]->metadata)` say?

Comment: Kindly add the print output of metadata. Did you tried `metadata` as array instead of object?

Comment: added var dump above - gettype returns object

Comment: Foreach can loop only through Arrays, it can loop through objects PUBLIC properties or objects that implement some form of \Iterator interface. Since this is a Stripe object, I would assume those properties aren't public, especially password_hash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the method

```
public function __toArray($recursive = false)
{
    if ($recursive) {
        return Util\Util::convertStripeObjectToArray($this->_values);
    } else {
        return $this->_values;
    }
}
```

like this:

```
$matchArray = $matchUser->__toArray();
```

to a deeper understanding of what methods are available please take a look at this url:

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/StripeObject.php

hope it helps

Comment: Just took the section of the object I wanted to iterate over and used this function.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a couple of months old and it already has an accepted answer. I think there is a better approach to it though.

I think the developers of the PHP library for the Stripe API prefix some methods with __ (double underscore) to indicate the method is protected or private, which is an old convention from the times when method visibility was not a thing in PHP. Now the __ prefix is reserved for magic methods as stated in [PHP: Magic Methods - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php):

> PHP reserves all function names starting with __ as magical.

After taking a closer look to the [`StripeObject` class](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/StripeObject.php) I think the `jsonSerialize` method that is defined as below is a better choice.

```php
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return $this->__toArray(true);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```php
$matchUserArray = $matchUser->jsonSerialize();

// Output "hello" 
echo $matchUserArray['data'][0]['metadata']['testitem']
```